# read and write from a txt file (assembly)

Tags: file, assembly, dos, x86-16

I am writing a project in assembly language and I have a problem with read from a file and print on the screen what is written in it.

I took part of the code (which is the read and print part) and I tried to fix it and re write it and i still have a problem.

If someone can help me I'll be more then happy

**this is the code :**

```
org 100h
mov ah,0ah
mov dx,offset place
int 21h             ; getting the place(directory) of the file   

mov si,offset place
inc si
mov dx,[si]
inc dx
mov si,dx
mov [si],0

mov ah,02
mov dl,13
int 21h
mov ah,02
mov dl,10
int 21h

mov ah,0ah
mov dx,offset filename
int 21h            ;getting the file name 

mov si,offset filename
inc si
mov dx,[si]
inc dx
mov si,dx
mov [si],0 

mov ah,02
mov dl,13
int 21h
mov ah,02
mov dl,10
int 21h


call gotoplace     ;go to the place of the file
;------------------

call openfile      ;open the file 
;------------------

mov ah,3fh
mov si,offset filehandle
mov bx,[si]              ;move file adress to bx
mov cx,40000             ;numbers of bytes to read
mov dx,offset buff       ;pointer to read buffer
int 21h 

mov si,offset filesize   ;move si pointer to filesize
mov [si],ax              ;move to filesize how many bytes read 
;------------------       

;writing on the screen -> 
mov bx,offset buff   ;move bx pointer of buffer
mov si,offset filesize
mov cx,[si]          ;move cx how many to write

startwrite:

mov ah,2
mov dl,[bx] ;move dl letter in place [bx]
int 21h

inc bx
dec cx
jnz startwrite


proc gotoplace
    mov ah,3bh
    mov dx,offset place ;move offset place to dx
    add dx,2
    int 21h

    ret

endp gotoplace    

proc openfile

    mov ah,3d
    mov al,2  ;open for read / write
    mov dx,offset filename  ;move dx offset filename 
    add dx,2
    int 21h   
    ;--------------------------

    mov si,offset filehandle ;move offset filehandle(location in the memory) to si
    mov [si],ax              ;move the file adress to the 'filehandle'(location in the meory' 

    ret

endp openfile

ret

filehandle dd ?
filename db 40
         db 42 dup (0) 
place db 40
      db 42 dup (0) 

      buff db 40000 dup (0)

filesize dd ?
```

**And this is the function that read and write :**

```
proc readprint

    call gotoplace     ;go to the place of the file
    ;------------------

    call openfile      ;open the file 
    ;------------------

    mov ah,3fh
    mov si,offset filehandle
    mov bx,[si]              ;move file adress to bx
    mov cx,40000             ;numbers of bytes to read
    mov dx,offset buff       ;pointer to read buffer
    int 21h 

    mov si,offset filesize   ;move si pointer to filesize
    mov [si],ax              ;move to filesize how many bytes read 
    ;------------------       
    mov ah,2
    mov bh,0
    mov dh,1
    mov dl,1
    int 10h  ;Move the cursor to the start of the page
    ;writing on the screen -> 
    mov bx,offset buff   ;move bx pointer of buffer
    mov si,offset filesize
    mov cx,[si]          ;move cx how many to write

    startwrite:

    mov ah,2
    mov dl,[bx] ;move dl letter in place [bx]
    int 21h

    inc bx
    dec cx
    jnz startwrite

    ;------------------

    ret

endp readprint
```

Comment: You get any errors? What exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: when I run the code in emu8086 i don't see any error .

Comment: you should include any errors or warnings that your assembler gave you, and explain (unambiguously) what the expected behavior is and also what the actual behavior is.

Comment: and it should open a file read it and print on the screen

Comment: In "proc openfile" you have "mov ah,3d", it should be 3dH.

Answer (score 2):

These are the problems in your code :

- In `proc openfile` you use the number 3d that should be 3dH.
- After capturing "place" and "filename" you insert chr(0) at the end of both strings, but you are doing `mov dx,[si]`, which is an error because the length of the string (pointed by `[si]`) is one byte, and you are moving two bytes to `dx`.
- The file size type is DD but it should be DW, remember you will use this number in `cx` to write to screen, that's why it must be DW.
- You forgot to finish the program properly.

There is another problem that it's not your fault. EMU8086 has an issue when opening files. EMU8086 runs programs in subdirectory `c:\emu8086\mybuild`, sometimes EMU8086 doesn't allow to open files outside the subdirectory `mybuild`. In order to work with files in EMU8086, store them in `c:\emu8086\mybuild`.

Next is your code. I fixed the problems and commented the code that changes the subdirectory, changes are pointed by arrows <========= :

```
org 100h

;mov ah,0ah
;mov dx,offset place
;int 21h             ; getting the place(directory) of the file   

;ADD 0 TO END OF STRING <==================================

;mov si,offset place
;inc si
;mov dl,[si]         ;<== LENGTH OF STRING IS BYTE, NOT WORD
;mov dh,0            ;<================== CLEAR DH TO USE DX
;inc dx
;add si,dx           ;<========= SI POINTS TO FINAL CHAR + 1
;mov [byte ptr si],0 ;<========= THE NUMBER ZERO HAS NO SIZE 

;LINE BREAK.

;;mov ah,02
;mov dl,13
;int 21h
;mov ah,02
;mov dl,10
;int 21h

mov ah,0ah
mov dx,offset filename
int 21h            ;getting the file name 

;ADD 0 TO END OF STRING <==================================

mov si,offset filename
inc si
mov dl,[si]         ;<== LENGTH OF STRING IS BYTE, NOT WORD
mov dh,0            ;<================== CLEAR DH TO USE DX
inc dx
add si,dx           ;<========= SI POINTS TO FINAL CHAR + 1
mov [byte ptr si],0 ;<========= THE NUMBER ZERO HAS NO SIZE 

;LINE BREAK.

mov ah,02
mov dl,13
int 21h
mov ah,02
mov dl,10
int 21h


;call gotoplace     ;go to the place of the file
;------------------

call openfile      ;open the file 
;------------------

mov ah,3fh
mov si,offset filehandle
mov bx,[si]              ;move file adress to bx
mov cx,40000             ;numbers of bytes to read
mov dx,offset buff       ;pointer to read buffer
int 21h 

mov si,offset filesize   ;move si pointer to filesize
mov [si],ax              ;move to filesize how many bytes read 
;------------------       

;writing on the screen -> 
mov bx,offset buff   ;move bx pointer of buffer
mov si,offset filesize
mov cx,[si]          ;move cx how many to write

startwrite:

mov ah,2
mov dl,[bx] ;move dl letter in place [bx]
int 21h

inc bx
dec cx
jnz startwrite

;WAIT UNTIL USER PRESS ANY KEY  <===========================
  mov  ah,7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM  <==========================================
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h           


proc gotoplace
    mov ah,3bh
    mov dx,offset place ;move offset place to dx
    add dx,2
    int 21h

    ret

endp gotoplace    

proc openfile

    mov ah,3dH
    mov al,2  ;open for read / write
    mov dx,offset filename  ;move dx offset filename 
    add dx,2
    int 21h   
    ;--------------------------

    mov si,offset filehandle ;move offset filehandle(location in the memory) to si
    mov [si],ax              ;move the file adress to the 'filehandle'(location in the meory' 

    ret

endp openfile

ret

filehandle dd ?
filename db 40
         db 42 dup (0) 
place db 40
      db 42 dup (0) 

      buff db 40000 dup (0)

filesize dw ?  ;<========= IN 8086 WE CANNOT READ MORE THAN 64KB.
```

Comment: I have a question somewhat similar to this one  I can easily read from a file if the code is only for reading but if the code involves write as well then i am not able to read. The data from file does not get Read into the memory if i do write and read at same time why ?